# How to get the Cartesian mapping for two datatables through LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, union

I have two `datatables` and I want to to make a `Cartesian mapping` between the two `datatables`, using `LINQ`.

For example if I have Two datatables `DT1` ,`DT2`:

## DT1 :

```
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

---

## DT2 :

```
1   D
2   E
3   F
```

---

I want the result:

```
    A    D
    A    E
    A    F
    B    D
    B    E
    B    F
    C    D
    C    E
    C    F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var newDatatable = from p1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                   from p2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                   select new {p1, p2};
```

Then fill `newDatatable` into a new `DataTable`.

Comment: I wanna the result in another datatable please

Comment: Could i use `CopyToDatatable();` directly ?

Comment: @just_name, It should work, but use the query as an input for this method.

Comment: I don't find this method when i use `newDatatable.`

Comment: @just_name, sorry your query should be of type `IEnumerable<DataRow>` in order to be resolved in it `DataTable newDataTable = yourquery.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();`, see the examples section in this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
from d1 in DT1
from d2 in DT2
select new {d1.col1, d2.col1,}
```